# multiple databases on global level in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am aware of multiple database support in Rails 6 but it seems to be on model level, like we tell for each model that from which database it belongs to.

A client wants two databases for production server with similar schema say

```
primary_live_database
secondary_test_database
```

idea is that app will send a header parameter to give a hint to its test app or live, and depending upon this we will switch database.

how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really just want to setup an additional environment. This is done by setting the `RAILS_ENV` environmental variable. Usually such an environment is called *staging* but its really up to you whatever you want to call it.

Setting `RAILS_ENV = 'staging'` will:

- Cause Rails to load `config/environments/staging.rb`.
- Rails will use the `staging` settings in `config/database.yml`.
- The secrets for `staging` will be loaded from `config/secrets.yml.enc` if your Rails version supports per env secrets.
- `Rails.env == 'staging'` and `Rails.env.staging? == true`.

This lets you run a near copy of the production environment but with different settings. For example you often want to limit access to the staging environment to collaborators or push changes to the staging environment to collaborate on features that may not be production ready.

If your clients reaction is `Waaaaaaah, so much work!` then you can use a callback in your ApplicationController to call `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`. I don't recommend it though.

Comment: If the client's reaction is "Waaaaaaah, so much work!" wait until they realize the maintenance bills for adhoc context switching.

Comment: @engineersmnky can you explain why switching databases would lead to increased maintainence costs? Are you talking about the code complexity or actual infrastructure costs?

Comment: @max so I just have to set RAILS_ENV = 'development' and RAILS_ENV = 'production', depending upon request or what? and I can use existing development environment?

Comment: @max infrastructure difference is nominal (one more or less hosting for the code base) code complexity is likely to be an issue as well as debugging. I have seen similar (conceptually) "non-conventional" setups also wreak significant havok should the client leave firm A and transfer the code base to firm B. Rails (and ruby in general) offers such significant flexibility that sometimes what might seem like minor idiosyncrasies now can end up with a significant cost in the future.

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal no - the key takeaway is you don't want to do it per request. Setup different containers, heroku apps or whatever infrastructure your client uses. Have the stating environment on different urls such as a subdomain. Setting it per request would screw with optimizations like process forking.

Comment: " and I can use existing development environment?" - that would defeat the entire point of having a mirror of the production environment. Also providing remote access to a Rails app running development settings is a no-no for security reasons. You can host a staging environment locally if you want to and provide access via a tunnel like Ngrok. I would not really recommend doing this on something like your workstation unless you feel like booting it up every time the client wants to access it.